# Android Studio: I can't download a list of pictures from Firebase server

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, download, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase to download pictures from the server and display them in a listview in Android Studio. Specifically, it's a list of pictures that I store in an array which I later use for the listview.
If I need to download just one image the code works just fine, the problem is that when I receive more than one the listview displays only blank images with the exception of the last one, which is the right one for that spot. I've already used that listview for other stuff and I know it works.
Here is my method:

```
public void fetchImages(Map<String,Object> bitmaps) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : bitmaps.entrySet()) {
        storageRef = storage.getReference().child(entry.getKey());
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("FileTemp", "jpg");
            storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    returnedBitmaps[i++] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I know that I always get a number of pictures equal to the array dimension so I don't get errors in that part. If I try `taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()` I get the exact number of bytes the pictures from the server have so I think the pictures are there and i'm just doing something wrong when I'm trying to display them. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: this is the method I'm using on my listview:

```
public void fixImages () {
    listItemsName = new String[returnedContacts.length];
    imageNameBitmap = new Bitmap[returnedContacts.length];
    int count = 0;
    while (count < returnedContacts.length) {
        listItemsName[count] = returnedContacts[count].name + " " + returnedContacts[count].lastName;
        imageNameBitmap[count] = returnedBitmaps[count];
        count++;
    }
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    try {
        listAdapterBitmap = new ListAdapterBitmap(CheckFollows.this, listItemsName, imageNameBitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapterBitmap);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(returnedContacts[position] != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CheckFollows.this, PersonBrowsed.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The listview displays on the right side a name and a last name using the `listItemName` array while showing a picture on the left side, using the `imageNameBitmap` array.
Class ListAdapterBitmap:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

class ListAdapterBitmap extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity Context;
    private final String [] ListItemsName;
    private final Bitmap [] ImageName;

    ListAdapterBitmap(Activity context, String [] content, Bitmap [] ImageName) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_items, content);
        this.Context = context;
        this.ListItemsName = content;
        this.ImageName = ImageName;
    }
    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View view,@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = Context.getLayoutInflater();
        View ListViewSingle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);
        TextView ListViewItems = (TextView)ListViewSingle.findViewById(R.id.tvSportName);
        ImageView ListViewImage = (ImageView)ListViewSingle.findViewById(R.id.imgSportPicture);
        ListViewItems.setText(ListItemsName[position]);
        ListViewImage.setImageBitmap(ImageName[position]);
        return ListViewSingle;
    }

}
```

Comment: _so I think the pictures are there and i'm just doing something wrong when I'm trying to display them._ It sounds like you are confident the posted code works and the problem is elsewhere.  Add to your post the code where you use `returnedBitmaps` to populate your ListView.

Comment: Downloading of the images occurs asynchronously, and depending on the number and size of the images, could take many seconds. From the posted code, it's not clear that you are checking that all the downloads have completed and it is safe to call `fixImages()`.  Does your code handle that?

Comment: @BobSnyder Well, `fixImages()` is called only in this case: `if(i == returnedBitmaps.length - 1)` so yes, that sould give it the time to download as it's called when the array is full. What I think is that `localFile` may be overriden by the new image every time there's an iteration and that's why it only shows the last one but I don't know how I can prove it. Could that be possible?

Comment: Change the declaration of `localFile` in the try-block: `File localFile = File.createTempFile("FileTemp", "jpg");`

Comment: @BobSnyder I did but I had to add the `final` keyword for it to work. Now it finally loads all the images, thank you so much! Sometimes it mixes the right order for them to show up and I don't know why but I think I can take it from here. I still don't get why it's now loading, was that an override problem? Anyway, thanks again